# Momentjs DST timezone conversion wrong when date is not DST

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm working on an app where dates are stored as strings in the server, and are created in Eastern Time. I've been trying to display the dates in the front-end as local time using momentjs, and conversion seems pretty straightforward:

```
var date = moment.tz(serverDate, 'America/New_York');
var convertedDate = date.local().format();
```

This works under normal cases, but I ran into a problem when I set my local timezone to Eastern Time during testing (i.e., same timezone as server dates so all dates should be reflected in the frontend as is). Dates when DST wasn't in effect were shifted by one hour. From my understanding, this is due to the moment library using *current* timezone offsets when converting from one timezone to another. ET's offset during DST is -300, while ET moments for dates outside DST is -240. I have tried other methods of converting using the moment library, but all of them still boils down to using the incorrect offsets.

```
var date = moment.tz('2018-05-30T04:00:00', 'America/New_York');
var converted = date.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format(); //"2018-05-30T03:00:00-05:00"
```

Is there a way with momentjs to handle these cases?